# LAMP (isothermal amplification), hydroxy naphtol blue , disodium salt" or just hydroxy naphtol blue?

Tags: pcr

I am reproducing this work on LAMP (isothermal amplification)
Article A new visually improved and sensitive loop mediated isotherm...
,

but I am a bit confused  about the difference between "hydroxy naphtol blue", and "hydroxy naphtol blue , disodium salt". They hav a very huge difference in price. One is 470 USD and 40 USD for the same aliquote.  Or for LAMP there is no difference?

E.g. Price for HNB

https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/mm/104593?lang=de&region=CH&gclid=CjwKCAjw4rf6BRAvEiwAn2Q76quMK0jzJnsEL5Dsjh_rwYhGCz_Foj5ybiH4o8vNCZQ8S53qkaiA9RoCisIQAvD_BwE

and HNB disodium salt
https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/219916?lang=de&region=CH

Comment: The sodium salt is the conjugate base of the raw compound, likely formed by reacting it with a strong base like Sodium Hydroxide. I'm curious what function it serves in the LAMP protocol. Can you cite the protocol? They might be capable of serving similar functions in solution, but they are not interchangeable in a reaction recipe, as one will lower the pH of an aqueous mixture more than the other. Probably a better question for https://chemistry.stackexchange.com

Comment: I just found a LAMP protocol which provided a CAS number corresponding to the Hydroxynaphtol Blue, not the sodium salt. Make sure to cross-check the methods section of the work you are trying to reproduce though.